# SNMP: OID(s) for Manufacturer/Model of Device?

Tags: snmp

I am using SNMP to get system information for dynamic message boards. I was able to find an OID for system description and am wondering if there are OIDs which will return manufacturer and model information. A good resource would be acceptable as well, as I've been working from the NEMA site and using the NTCIP 1203 documentation for DMS but found Global Time in NTCIP 1201 and GPS location in 1204 and could surely benefit from being pointed to additional documentation. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am afraid, but there is no standard SNMP variable that contains model and manufacturer for a device. In most cases, vendors use their proprietary fields to store this information. And what makes it even worse is that the vendors might use different SNMP OIDs for different models!

However, you might check the entity-mib which contains a SNMP table called "entPhysicalTable". For many devices, this table contains an entry for the chassis itself (entPhysicalClass=3) and that entry usually contains the manufacturer, model and serial number. But be aware, that this table is not supported by all SNMP devices. Howevery, you might try to read it and if it returns data, then you're fine.

Otherwise, you can only check the private MIBs for the devices you have in your network.